# Proxy issues using WFS from Cadcorp GeognoSIS

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, proxy

I have web and WMS/WFS servers hosted on the same machine, although on different ports.
I'm currently using OpenLayers to consume the WMS feeds which works well, but now I need to allow the user to extract info about objects so am trying to incorporate WFS into the OpenLayers setup.
Being on different ports, I've set up proxy.asp to do the WFS requests:

```
<%
set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
strURL = Request("url")
objHttp.open "GET", strURL, False
objHttp.Send

If objHttp.status = 200 Then
    Response.Expires = 90
    Response.ContentType = "application/xml;charset=UTF-8"
    Response.BinaryWrite objHttp.responseBody
    set objHttp = Nothing
End If
%>
```

I've tested the proxy using this URL:
http:///maps/proxy.asp?url=http%3A//:4326/OgcService/WFS.impl?service=wfs?request=getCapabilities

This returns the GetCapabilities which is identical to that returned if I access it directly, but without the proxy.

However, when using this WFS, via proxy, I can't get OpenLayers to display any content. At this stage it could well be my OpenLayers code, which I can post if necessary, but the same WFS URL via proxy doesn't work in MapInfo or Cadcorp MapModeller (it does with just the base URL). I suspect the proxy is the issue.

Any ideas what the issue is likely to be?

Comment: Does Firebug show any error?

Comment: I get a console message for line 748 in OpenLayers.js: `POST http://myserver/maps/proxy.asp?url=http%3A//myserver:4326/OgcService/WFS.impl`

Comment: The response is: `<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<ogc:ServiceExceptionReport xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://myserver:4326/OgcService/WFS.impl?GetSchema&amp;name=OGC/wfs/1.0.0/OGC-exception.xsd"><ogc:ServiceException>Invalid or missing version parameter.</ogc:ServiceException></ogc:ServiceExceptionReport>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the Cadcorp.OGC.CGI.exe (which you can just rename to, for example, wfs.exe) instead of your proxy.asp. It is configured via a companion INI file, and passes on everything that GeognoSIS needs.

Or, you could use WMS GetFeatureInfo instead of WFS, for a simplified response